# Shared data set for cached reports?

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008

Is there a way in SSRS to create a snapshot for a report that uses a shared dataset? We are looking for a way to dynamically set the server and credentials in SSRS, but it seems when the shared dataset is used there is no way to cache a report.

Answer (score 1):

Two things that I think may help you:

1. You can create a dynamic connection string from parameters you pass in.  However you lose intellisense when creating this so generally I use an actual database first to do my dataset then change the connection string later:

   A. Create a variable @Server, set it to text:

   B. Create a local DataSource, this must be local as you cannot share a data source that is dynamic, to my knowledge as it has no input to go on thus a shared must have set inputs.

   C. On the side of 'Connection string:' hit the 'fx' button to get a dynamic connection string.  Build a connection string of text with your parameter being an input:

   ```
   ="Data Source=" & Parameters!Server.Value & ";Initial Catalog=(DBName)"
   ```

   D. You NOW have to set up a dataset to bind to @Server variable or else someone just needs to do plain text to guess at a server.  For this reason I usually create a dataset like

   ```
   select 'Server1' as Server
   union
   select 'Server2'
   union
   select 'Server3'
   ```
2. You can handle the cache aspect COMPLETELY from the hosted end and not worry about the report stuff.  Just go to a report once deployed and choose 'Manage'>'Snapshot Options'> Set your preferences.

EDIT: You probably want another variable for the database or else you will assume a same database structure all the time.